# Maintain scroll position in list when new items get added

Tags: angular

I have a list of items which I am displaying using `*ngFor`

```
<div id="container">
  <div 
      [class.selected]="selectedItem.id == item.id"
      #container 
      *ngFor="let item of items; indexBy: byId">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>
```

I keep updating the lists array periodically.

```
this.listService.index((items) => this.items = items)
```

I have a `selectedItem` which is used to highlight an item on selection.

When I update the lists, new items can be added above the selected item (mostly) and below the selected item. When that happens the selected item moves away from current view position.
I want to adjust the scrollOffset of parent div is such a way the position of items in the list remains at the same view position.

**Update:**

To do this, I am saving

```
this.offset; = this.container.scrollHeight - this.container.scrollTop;
```

and added a line after updating `this.items`

```
this.listService.index((items) => {
  this.items = items
  this.container.scrollTop = this.container.scrollHeight - this.offset;
})
```

this doesnt work but, wrapping this with timeout works exactly how I wanted.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.scrollPosition.restore()
}, 300)
```

After updating `this.items` there is a delay in rendering the new dom elements.

How can I get the event that new elements have been added?

Comment: Did you find a way to way to trigger an event when item rendering finished?

Comment: As using `ViewChild` to access a dom element is considered a security risk, have you found any other solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think something like this will work for you:

Template

```
<div id="container" #cont>...
```

Component

```
@ViewChild('cont') contEl: any;

thisIsCalledWhenNewItemISAdded() {
   let current = this.contEl.nativeElement.scrollTop;

   // ...Item added

   this.contEl.nativeElement.scrollTop = current;
}
```

So you use the `@ViewChild` decorator to get the element in your component. Then you capture the `scrollTop` before a new item gets added and you set it back once the item is added.

Comment: the scrollTop remains the same after updating items anyway. I want to change scrollTop so that the items in view does not get pushed down when new item gets added on top. Updated my question. Thanks

Comment: this answer is not working for me, is there any other solution?